# Using facebook sdk on Android without transferring the project to gradle

Tags: android, facebook, gradle

I have a huge Android project that I develop in Netbeans and now when I want to integrate face book's plugin into it, I see in facebook's tutorials that I need Android Studio and Gradle.

How can I integrate facebook's plugin without transferring whole project into gradle?

The sdk is a gradle project. I have zero knowledge in it and I didn't find anything online that gets me closer to the goal. I didn't succeed to build the SDK project once I downloaded gradle plugin.

Comment: I don't think you need Android studio and gradle, the documentation is only showing you how to do it using gradle. There should be an option to actually download the sdk. Why not use android studio anyway? :D

Comment: Oh man... I like those answers. Me: "Hi, I need a new engine oil for my track." You: "Why not buying a new track?"

Comment: Lol, I did kind of gave an answer before the question tho :D

Comment: You're funny. XD Yeah, you did give an answer, but not my question. From what I wrote, it easy to see that I do understand that I probably don't need android studio, neither gradle and I'm asking how to import the plugin. Maybe it'd be clearer if I'd mentioned that Gradle is what I'm least familiar with among all the above.

Comment: Moving to AS was actually the only choice in the end, so you were right. I'm very upset that I can't keep working in my favourite Netbeans. :(